# How can I detect the Enter key in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, events, firefox, typescript

I am able to successfully detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in Internet Explorer 10, Chromium and Opera, but not in Firefox.

I have found a few pages on here, though they do not work in Firefox either. Am I doing something wrong, here?

TypeScript:

```
function HandleKeyPress(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (key == 13) {
        // We got this.
        var textbox = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tbox");
        sayHello(textbox.value);
    }
}
```

Resulting JavaScript (identical):

```
function HandleKeyPress(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
        var textbox = document.getElementById("tbox");
        sayHello(textbox.value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="dfgdfgdfg" id="tbox" onkeypress="HandleKeyPress(event)" />
```

I can't use any external libraries, I have to do this in pure JavaScript (or a language that compiles to pure JS).

---

## Update:

---

I just installed Firebug and in the Consolw pane I noticed (just after pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> jey on the textfield:

```
http://localhost:1058/Default.cshtml?someValue=dfgdfgdfgkjkhj


<p>You said: dfgdfgdfgkjkhj</p>
```

See below for the pic:

[image]

*Notice* that the page itself has not updated the value of the `response` paragraph to what was entered in the textbox, **but**, Firebug does indeed say that it was successfully posted.

Now, since this code works on every other browser (IE, Chrome/Canary and <, Opera, Safari), my question is, maybe Firefox **is** detecting the key event, but the part that isn't working is after that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, every version of Firefox will correctly set the `which` property of the event object in the `keypress` event handler. It won't always set the `keyCode` property, but that shouldn't matter since you check for either. Can you make a fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Here's an example - focus the input and press any key to get an alert. The enter key should alert `true`. http://jsfiddle.net/YUQuU/

Comment: Thanks @JamesAllardice: I just tried a JSFiddle, but it wouldn't even work in IE on the fiddle site. :/ Here's the link anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/bMbUt/1/

Comment: @JamesKent - The fiddle doesn't work because the JS is included in the wrong place. Here's your fiddle again updated: http://jsfiddle.net/bMbUt/2/

Comment: @JamesAllardice: WTH? I just checked your link (http://jsfiddle.net/bMbUt/2/), and (in Firefox 15.0) it works! But when I use the exact same code in a diff page it doesn't. :/ That's weird.

Comment: @JamesKent - Yup, that's what I was getting at ;) It must be something else in your script as it should work fine. See my comments on the various answers. Firefox always sets the `which` property to the correct value for the Enter key in the keypress event object.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Thank you, though I don't quite understand how it could be something else in my scripts. 'Cause right now, the code I posted in my question is the *only* code I have. So I don't understand how identical code can work online (jsfiddle), but not on my other page. I am thinking maybe it has something to do with TypeScript? I am posting the JavaScript (the resulting code)

Comment: But then again, I don't think it has anything to do with TypeScript, since the resulting code is perfectly fine, imo, and practically identical.

Comment: Perhaps pressing enter is submitting the form before the HandleKeyPress can fire?

Comment: @JamesKent - Is the input part of a form? If so, are you cancelling the submit event? There is nothing wrong with your code - it should work in Firefox (we've seen from the fiddle that that's the case).

Comment: @JamesAllardice & James, nah, there's no form at all. Just 1 textfield.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I just installed Firebug. And I think I'm getting closer to figuring this out. I'm updating my question to provide more detail.

Comment: Just updated question to provide my latest findings.

Answer (score 5):

You should change `onkeypress` to `onkeydown` as `onkeypress` only fires for printable characters in some implementations.

Your existing code should work with `onkeydown`.

Comment: Thanks @Sohnee! But, with onkeydown, some people are a little slow on releasing their finger from the button and thus would cause the event to fire multiple times. I originally tried onkeydown and if you hold the Enter key down for too long, it just repeats the event. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `onkeyup` would be ok for this?

Comment: Yes - both `onkeypress` and `onkeydown` fire multiple times while the key is held down. `onkeyup` will work as long as the order of execution works for what you are doing (i.e. if anything else happens on the other two events, `onkeyup` may be too late).

Comment: In Firefox the `keypress` event *does* fire for the Enter key, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll use onkeyup, since it'll be inserting/updating database and I don't want multiple calls.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I am always concerned about one solution that works in all browsers. `onkeyup` / `onkeydown` works the same everywhere (except how you obtain the character). `onkeypress` differs.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<input type="text" value="dfgdfgdfg" id="tbox" onkeypress="HandleKeyPress(event)" />
```

And define the function `HandleKeyPress` as:

```
function HandleKeyPress(evt){
    var key = evt.which || evt.charCode || evt.keyCode || 0;

    if (key == 13) ...
}
```

Comment: Hey @Renato, just a quicky... What purpose does the `0` have in there?

Comment: @JamesKent: Be sure that you will not receive an `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish by using jQuery like this

```
$(".input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Alien, I forgot to mention, I can't use jQuery for this, which sucks. I have updated my question. +1 anyway.

Comment: You just gave me an idea. I could look into the jQuery source to see how they handle cross-browser stuff for this.

Comment: @JamesKent you welcome, I thought you must be using so just gave a simple example :)

Comment: While jquery is a good library, I hate it when people pull it out of a black hat when the question doesn't mention it at all.

Comment: @Jasper did you read it does give people other options to accomplish a certain task, some people might not be aware that this can be done easily by jQuery

Comment: I *used to* hate it when I was given answers telling me to use jQuery; but then I realised I only hated it because I didn't fully understand how to use jQuery. I also think it's kinda ironic how now that I actually want to use jQuery, and know how to, I still can't.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Then ask about jquery in the comments. An answer is meant to be just that: an answer. It shouldn't be a "maybe you can use this library, but you might need to learn the library first or accept that you have no idea what your code does"